# User defined function to R library function like avg()

Tags: r

I created a user defined function in R for checking whether a given number is prime or not. How can I make that user defined function as library function like `avg` or `sd`?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Is there any reason why the function has to be "user-defined"?

Comment: `myUDF <- function(x){ some cool code; return(results) }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(numbers)

isPrime(561)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: but if there is no user defined function and I have created one then how can I add it to the library. Because whenever I created an user defined function and I want to use it I need to run the total script...

Comment: can you please help me with it..

Comment: Provide the code you've run in your total script

Comment: remainder<-function(x,y)
{
result<-x %% y
cat(result,"\n")
}

Comment: this is the sample code for finding the remainder value, lets say when ever I want to find the remainder I need to execute the total code so for example if the code is too long its difficult execute all lines

Comment: place it in the Rprofile.site file http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the startup script. Use this site for more information. [Customizing R:startup](http://www.r-bloggers.com/customizing-r-startup-script/).

There is an Rprofile file that then refers to a `.First()` function. That user added functions to the .First function. I looked for it on my system and found an Rprofile file in the R folder, but did not find the latter.

I started going through the system files to do it myself. But not knowing exactly what I'm doing can cause more damage in the long run. Screwing something there may require reinstallation of the program.

Perhaps someone knows an easier way. Try it and report back, but I wouldn't recommend messing with system files unless you are very careful and the functions are absolutely necessary to your working environment startup. gl

## Update

I found the Rprofile.site file in the R/etc directory. I added a `.First()` function. On opening RStudio in the next session, the packages I added loaded, but the function I put in it did not.

## Update 2

I got it to work. I added this `.First` function to the `Rprofile.site` file in the etc folder.

```
.First <- function(){
 library(dplyr)
 library(stringr)
 source('path/myfinctions.R')
}
```

And it loaded the packages and the functions that I have in the 'myfunctions.R' file. Thanks for asking this question as I have a place to save the functions that I want to define and load into R automatically. : )

Comment: sure, thanks for your valuable suggestions and ansewers

Comment: I updated my answer after trying it.